# Create and fill new columns based on range information from two other columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(group  = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                 start  = c(2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7),
                 stop   = c(4, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9),
                 unstop = c(5, 7, 10, 7, 9, 10))
```

I now want to do the following:

- Create new columns that have the names "week_1", "week_2" ... "week_10", "week_n".
- Within each group for the FIRST ROW, I check which weeks the row was "active" in, i.e. it started in week 2, and stopped in week 4, so the row was active in week 2, 3, 4. I now want to populate the respective week columns with a 1.
- Within each group for ALL OTHER EXCEPT THE LAST ROW, I do the same check, but now populate based on the unstop value of that row and the stop value of the next row.
- Within each group for the LAST ROW, I do the same check, but now populate based on the range from unstop to 10 (which is the last week in my case).

I have a theoretical way. The problem is that my real-life data has 80k rows (consisting of 60k groups) and I'd need to create ~200 of such week-columns. Even filtering on 10 rows only takes ~30s for the code below.

So I'm looking for a more elegent/smarter/FASTER solution.

Expected outcome:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 14
# Groups:   group [2]
  group start  stop unstop week_1 week_2 week_3 week_4 week_5 week_6 week_7 week_8 week_9 week_10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>   <int>
1     1     2     4      5      0      1      1      1      0      0      0      0      0       0
2     1     2     7      7      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0       0
3     1     2     8     10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       1
4     2     7     7      7      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0       0
5     2     7     8      9      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1       0
6     2     7     9     10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       1
```

Below is how I would have approached it generally (of course not with manually defining each row_number. Apart from that, the code is also wrong and does not give the expected 0/1 values. It alsow throws many warnings. And finally, this code already runs a few seconds just for this small test data. It would run one month for my 80k/200col data set.

```
add_weeks <- as_tibble(as.list(setNames(rep(0L, 10),
                                        paste0("week_", 1:10))))

df |> 
  bind_cols(add_weeks) |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(across(num_range("week_", 1:10),
                ~ if_else(row_number() == 1 & str_extract(cur_column(), "\\d+$") %in% start:stop,
                          1L,
                          .)),
         across(num_range("week_", 1:10),
                ~ if_else(row_number() == 2 & str_extract(cur_column(), "\\d+$") %in% unstop:lead(stop),
                          1L,
                          .)),
         across(num_range("week_", 1:10),
                ~ if_else(row_number() == 3 & str_extract(cur_column(), "\\d+$") %in% unstop:10,
                          1L,
                          .)))
```

Comment: You should say how you plan to analyze this. If you intend to do time varying covariants with survival analysis, it would be better to do in in a long format.

Comment: It's not some kind of modeling analysis. I'd also prefer to keep it in long format. But my colleagues for which i'm preparing the data use a tool that works better/only with wide-format data.

Comment: I’d make a matrix with names columns and assign with row and col indices. You can then either attach it as a matrix or convert to data frame.

Comment: Any hint how to do that? I'm not sure if I can follow.

Comment: Getting close. Need to know if all groups have exactly 3 lines?

Comment: So, I offered a solution that had a different result than you said was expected. Was it wrong?

Comment: I think your solution generally is fine, it's just that for the second condition I think we need `unstop[r]:stop[r+1]`. I also fixed one bug in my reprex in row 4 (where the stop value was smaller than the start value, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I think my contribution can be modified to fit all sorts of logic. The speed up is due to the indexing by character values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now tested code. Implementation of strategy described in comment:

> I’d make a matrix with names columns and assign with row and col indices. You can then either attach it as a matrix or convert to data frame.

```
Mat <- matrix(0, nrow(df), 10) # 200 for real case
maxwk <- 10
colnames(Mat) <- paste0("week", 1:maxwk)

# Add extra column that marks condition 
# If there are always exactly 3 row per group just rep(1:3, ngrps)

# Need to define a value for cond that identifies the three possibilities:
```

```
df$cond <- rep(1:3, length=nrow(df))  # assume all groups have exactly 3:

for ( r in 1:nrow(df) ) {
          # for first row in group
  if( df$cond[r] == 1){
     Idx <-  paste0("week", df$start[r]:df$stop[r] ) #start:stop
     Mat[r, Idx] <- 1; next}
          # second
  if( df$cond[r] == 2){ 
     Idx <-  paste0("week" , df$stop[r]:df$unstop[r] )#  stop:unstop
     Mat[r, Idx] <- 1; next}
          # third
  if( df$cond[r] == 3){
    Idx  <- paste0("week", df$unstop[r]:maxwk )    # unstop:max
    Mat[r, Idx] <- 1; next}
  }
```

```
df
  group start stop unstop cond
1     1     2    4      5    1
2     1     2    7      7    2
3     1     2    8     10    3
4     2     7    6      7    1
5     2     7    8      9    2
6     2     7    9     10    3
> Mat
     week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7 week8 week9 week10
[1,]     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0      0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0      0
[3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
[4,]     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0      0
[5,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1      0
[6,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
```

You could `cbind` these.

There might be performance improvements possible. Could use `switch(cond, ...)` to dispatch to the correct logic rather than the `if( cond == .){ ., next}` method. This should be much faster than code that uses `ifelse` or `if_else`. If you want to see how that's implemented, then endorse the general strategy with a checkmark and I'll spend the time to add the alternate code.

- ran a benchmark after setting up both methods for 100 week maximum. * The warnings are from the code in the question:

```
> perf_results <- microbenchmark(
+     first.method    = do_first(df), sec.method=do_second(df), times=10)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> perf_results
Unit: microseconds
         expr         min        lq         mean       median          uq        max neval
 first.method 4385001.123 4416568.8 4581549.9624 4450691.5455 4615753.753 5350416.80    10
   sec.method     146.432     149.6     181.6137     188.2125     193.307     243.47    10
```

I wanted to see if a `switch` method of selecting the proper algorithm for a row would improve performance. It did and to a degree that surprised me. The `switch` function is analogous to the `case` function in Pascal and many other languages. It has two forms whose behavior is different depending on whether the first argument, `EXPR` is numeric or character. Here, the "dispatch" version is chosen because the "cond" column is numeric.

```
do_third= function(df){ Mat <- matrix(0, nrow(df), 100) # 200 for real case
maxwk <- 100
colnames(Mat) <- paste0("week", 1:maxwk)
df$cond <- rep(1:3, length=nrow(df))  # assume all groups have exactly 3: 
for( r in 1:nrow(df)) { switch( df[r,"cond"],      
         { # for first row in each group of 3
     Idx <-  paste0("week", df$start[r]:df$stop[r] ) #start:stop
     Mat[r, Idx] <- 1 }, 
          
          { # second row in group
     Idx <-  paste0("week" , df$stop[r]:df$unstop[r] )#  stop:unstop
     Mat[r, Idx] <- 1 },
          
          {# third
     Idx  <- paste0("week", df$unstop[r]:maxwk )    # unstop:max
     Mat[r, Idx] <- 1 } ) }
   }
```

New microbenchmark:

```
perf_results
Unit: nanoseconds
         expr        min         lq         mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 first.method 4304901359 4351893534 4387626725.8 4372151785 4416247096 4543314742    10   b
   sec.method     162803     173855    2588492.1     215309     216878   24081195    10  a 
   third.meth         34         53        610.6        877        940        963    10  a
```

Comment: Thanks IRTFM. Just a bit confused where you actually have the `switch` function? You used `select`, which I can't find any help for in base R.

Comment: I think select is from the tidyverse. I used switch on one machine and then swapped them on the second machine. I’ll try to clean up the mess.

Comment: `select` was definitely not the correct tidyverse equivalent. You could try `case_when`

Comment: Also, interestingly, while this Matrix approach and stuff is pretty fast, the overall runtime of the code in my real-life case is slightly longer or as high as running it with my `separate_rows` approach. I think it's because your solution is pretty fast for creating all teh week columns, but then I need to do several aggregation steps. Wheras using separate_rows gives me a small data set in long format from which I can do some faster aggregation. I didn't test exactly where the speed bottleneck is, but just found it interesting.

Comment: In that respect your first method overall seems to be even faster for me than using an approach with the third one.

Comment: I was not expecting the `switch` approach to be that much faster. I thought it should maybe be 10-20% faster. I took the next statements out of the last approach. They should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I'm posting my own solution of it. Apparently, adding 200 cols to a 60k data frame based on some conditions is extremely slow. So what I did instead is:

- Add one chr column with the info about the weeks via `str_c`.
- Create a smaller data set that just has the grouping var and this new info.
- Then use `separate_rows` on this week_info to get a long format data set.
- Then use `pivot_wider` and combine this info with the orginal data set.

Note that this approach works because I didn't mention in my initial post that I actually want to summarize the week info per group. So in the end I want to have one row per group. In the interest of keeping my question simple, I didn't add this to my question.

Having said that, the solution of @IRTFM is still considerably faster by a factor of 3.

```
df2 <- df |>
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(lead_stop = lead(stop, default = 0),
         n_rows = n(),
         row_number = row_number()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(split_weeks = case_when(n_rows == 1 & row_number == 1 ~ str_c(start:stop, collapse = ","),
                                 n_rows  > 1 & row_number == 1 ~ str_c(c(start:stop, unstop:lead_stop), collapse = ","),
                                 row_number == n_rows          ~ str_c(unstop:10, collapse = ","),
                                 TRUE                          ~ str_c(unstop:lead_stop, collapse = ",")))

df3 <- df2 |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarize(split_weeks = unique(str_c(split_weeks, collapse = ","))) |> 
  separate_rows(split_weeks, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) |>
  distinct() |> 
  mutate(value = 1L) |>
  full_join(y = data.frame(split_weeks = 1:10)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = split_weeks,
              names_prefix = "week_",
              values_from = value,
              values_fill = 0L,
              names_expand = TRUE) |> 
  filter(!is.na(group))

df4 <- df2 |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-split_weeks, -n_rows) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = row_number, values_from = -group) |> 
  bind_cols(x = df3 |> select(-group), y = _)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

periods <- tibble(
  group  = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  start  = c(2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7), 
  stop   = c(4, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9), 
  unstop = c(5, 7, 10, 7, 9, 10)
)

LAST <- 10
```

I think it makes sense to recode the intragroup start/stop/unstop logic to a
single start/stop for each row. Let’s call them rstart/rstop. Using your
rules, they can be created like this:

```r
(periods <- periods %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  transmute(
    period = row_number(),
    rstart = if_else(period == 1L, start, unstop),
    rstop  = if_else(period == 1L, stop,  lead(stop, default = LAST))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   group period rstart rstop
#>   <dbl>  <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1      1      2     4
#> 2     1      2      7     8
#> 3     1      3     10    10
#> 4     2      1      7     7
#> 5     2      2      9     9
#> 6     2      3     10    10
```

Now, we can generate the active stretches by group_by -> summarise. Here we
also add a indicator column `active` to show that the given weeks are active

```r
(periods <- periods %>% 
  group_by(group, period) %>% 
  summarise(
    weeks = rstart:rstop, 
    active = 1L, 
    .groups = "drop"
  ) 
)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   group period weeks active
#>   <dbl>  <int> <int>  <int>
#> 1     1      1     2      1
#> 2     1      1     3      1
#> 3     1      1     4      1
#> 4     1      2     7      1
#> 5     1      2     8      1
#> 6     1      3    10      1
#> 7     2      1     7      1
#> 8     2      2     9      1
#> 9     2      3    10      1
```

To have the non-observed weeks be present in the output after pivot_wider,
we can convert the week column to a factor and add the missing levels with
`fct_expand`. I’ve also added `fct_inseq` to make sure that the columns are
ordered as expected in the output. Once that is done, we can use `pivot_wider`
to get the wide format. Note the `names_expand = TRUE` argument which gives us
the levels we added to the week column.

```r
periods %>% 
  mutate(
    weeks = as_factor(weeks) %>% 
      fct_expand(as.character(1:LAST)) %>% 
      fct_inseq()
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = weeks, 
    names_expand = TRUE,
    values_from = active,
    values_fill = 0L, 
    names_prefix = "week"
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 12
#>   group period week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7 week8 week9 week10
#>   <dbl>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#> 1     1      1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0      0
#> 2     1      2     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0      0
#> 3     1      3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
#> 4     2      1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0      0
#> 5     2      2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1      0
#> 6     2      3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>